# Are there any mosques in Liechtenstein?

Tags: factoids, architecture, islam, liechtenstein, mosques

Are there any mosques in Liechtenstein? I like to visit a local mosque in every city I visit. Any Idea?

Comment: Are there any countries with a population greater than 30,000 that doesn't have mosques?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, [San Marino](http://www.crescentrating.com/san-marino-guide-for-muslim-travelers/item/2457-san-marino-overview.html?tmpl=component&print=1). (And North Korea until the Iranian embassy opened one a couple of years ago).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There seems to be a small mosque in Liechtenstein, the [green mosque](http://www.islamicfinder.org/getitWorld.php?id=74485) in [Triesen](http://goo.gl/maps/iPHPj) (about 2km from the city center of Vaduz), that is also mentioned in this [travel stub about Liechtenstein for "Halal-conscious travelers"](http://www.crescentrating.com/en/liechtenstein-city-guide-for-muslim-travelers/item/2032-liechtenstein-overview.html?tmpl=component&print=1). The local population of Muslims only numbers about 2000, but according to Wikipedia, there is [one yearly work permit offered for an Imam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islam_in_Liechtenstein).

Comment: Why *Only* 2000 ... ? That's more or less 5 % of the population (provided the information is correct)! Quite a lot.

Comment: Yet another perspective: Liechtenstein is a rather rural area. No big city. Compare the proportion of Muslims to the proportion in a comparable region in Germany. Then the 5% may be high again.

Comment: think they mean that it's not economical to build a large mosque for just 2000 people in a country where there's no active islamisation campaign funded by Saudi (or other big oil) groups so that the locals have to fund it themselves. This is a different situation from Indonesia, where villages are paid millions by Saudi groups to build mosques in exchange for sending people on the Hadj.

Comment: If only we could find someoby in Liechtenstein with a camera ...

Comment: Next time I'm there, I'll take a picture.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the address via  [zabihah](http://www.zabihah.com)

and [Rome2rio](http://www.rome2rio.com)  will answer you how to get there but it is not exact as real world.